# Using Angular Directives to Replace Bootstrap Class Assignment with HTML Tags

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I can see that this was an [AngularUI discussion](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/308) at one point...

I'm wondering if anyone else has implemented Angular directives that would allow me to replace traditional Bootstrap laden markup like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 offset2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with easier-to-read, element focused, markup similar to this

```
<container-fluid>
  <row>
    <column span4 offset2>
    </column>
  </row>
</container-fluid>
```

Seems like it would be easy enough to implement, which makes me think that someone else has done this already (or that it's not worth it for some reason (maybe there's a performance hit?))

Has anyone done this already already?

If not, are there reasons I shouldn't implement it myself?

Answer (score 0):

There are several Angular+Bootstrap projects, the prominent ones are [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) and [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), I'm quite sure you're already aware of them. Sure, they provide custom directives, but only for the things that require this (i.e. Bootstrap JS components).

> Seems like it would be easy enough to implement, which makes me think
>   that someone else has done this already (or that it's not worth it for
>   some reason (maybe there's a performance hit?))

Besides unnecessary performance overhead it would considerably diminish the value of Bootstrap as frontend framework - something that has learning curve that you already passed.

There are some developments in that direction - e.g. [angular-deckgrid](https://github.com/akoenig/angular-deckgrid), yet I'm not aware of any ambitious and comprehensive (web-oriented) framework like Bootstrap or Angular Material.

There would be more sense in tailoring custom syntax for yourself. You can take a look at [ui-alias](https://github.com/angular-ui/alias) (a part of ui-tools). It is rigid in its current state, but it a good example of smart approach to directives. And could be easily extended to make the mapping of classes to attributes and elements a breeze.